# How to delete object in JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON archive and I want find and delete one object. 
How to find and delete object in a JSON archive?

**Example:**

```
{
         "themes":[

                  {"name":"pepito",
                   "thumbnail":"http://nakome.16mb.com/samples/html/admin/",
                   "description":"Simple"},

                  // Delete this in php ---------
                  {"name":"juanito",  
                   "thumbnail":"http://nakome.16mb.com/samples/html/admin/",
                   "description":"Simple" }
                  // ----------------------------

                 ]
}
```

Comment: load it into php convert to php array/object delete it then write it to file?

Comment: I don't see how this question is relevant to PHP at all. Can you please make the question more clear? If are asking how to find a JSON object and modify it using PHP, please state that clearly. If you are asking how to do it in JavaScript then stress on that.

Comment: @GoogleGuy - What isn't clear about it? He wants to do it using PHP. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: @BarryChapman And you gathered this how? Nowhere in this question does the OP say I would like to do this in PHP. Further more the question lacks research and detail. It's about as straightforward as a spiraling staircase to me.

Comment: @GoogleGuy - Please, refrain from editing the tags or the post without getting clarification from the OP, or unless there is a glaringly obvious error

Comment: @BarryChapman Noted, but to me it was **glaringly** obvious that this question lacked any indication at all of PHP, since it's neither mentioned in the question's title nor is there even a hint of it in the example code or the question's body.  But I did leave a comment for the OP to ask for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, i want find and delete with php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without having to write your own parser (and given it's php) use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and turn it in to an object you want to work with, use [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) then re-[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the result.

That would be the easiest way without having to perform string parsing/searches.

Comment: Sorry, i want  find and delete with php.

Comment: @Nakome - And that's what this answer explains.